# Expected `async` block, found a different `async` block

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I was trying to use [`futures::future::select_ok`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select_ok.html) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e1cd2c20584a7108c3c03ae7e71427d3)):

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio; // 1.16.1
use futures; // 0.3.19

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let first_future = async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        Ok(3)
    };
    let second_future = async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        Err(())
    };
    let third_future = async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(300)).await;
        Ok(3)
    };
    futures::future::select_ok(&[first_future,second_future.await,third_future]).await;
}
```

and encountered the error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:19:47
   |
7  |       let first_future = async {
   |  ______________________________-
8  | |         tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
9  | |         Ok(3)
10 | |     };
   | |_____- the expected `async` block
...
19 |       futures::future::select_ok(&[first_future,second_future.await,third_future]).await;
   |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected opaque type, found enum `Result`
   |
   = note: expected opaque type `impl futures::Future<Output = [async output]>`
                     found enum `Result<_, ()>`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `playground` due to previous error
```

I have no idea what I'm missing here, would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each of the async blocks are treated as a different type, the same way closures are (IIRC). All of them implements `Future`, so you may want to actually dynamically dispatch them. For that you need to wrap them in `Pin<Box>`:

```rust
use futures;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio; // 1.16.1 // 0.3.19

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let first_future = async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        Ok(3)
    };
    let second_future = async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
        Err(())
    };
    let third_future = async {
        tokio::time::sleep(Duration::from_secs(300)).await;
        Ok(3)
    };
    let futures: [Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = Result<usize, ()>>>>; 3] = [
        Box::pin(first_future),
        Box::pin(second_future),
        Box::pin(third_future),
    ];
    futures::future::select_ok(futures).await;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c9c7838cc0c385d812b331c7edb76f95)

Comment: Note: this is partially unrelated to select_ok, because even trying to put values of different types (first_future and second_future) into an array is an error.

Comment: Do you know why `&dyn` or `Box<dyn>` won't work in this case, why do we need `Pin<Box<dyn>>`?

Comment: @battlmonstr, futures usually need to be pinned. It is the constrain that they will not be moved while making the computation.

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to the excellent answer by @Netwave:

In case someone is looking to avoid the heap allocation that `Pin<Box<dyn ..>>` requires, have a look at the [enum_dispatch](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) or [smallbox](https://crates.io/crates/smallbox) crates, which enable stack-allocated differently-sized objects.